# Windows XP freezes on welcome screen after resizing partitions

Tags: linux, windows-xp, freeze, gparted

I am using Windows XP and Linux on a dual boot system and after resizing the partitions, Windows hangs just before login. I shrank the Linux partition and enlarged the Windows partition using GParted.

Linux still works and the Windows files are still accessible from Linux, but Windows freezes before the login screen pops up, so that you can see a Windows logo on a blue background. The same happens in safe mode.

I tried tried `chkdsk /p`, `fixmbr` and `fixboot` inside the recovery console but the problem remains.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You MAY need to do a repair install. Boot off of the Windows XP CD, but instead of the recovery console, continue with setup. Right after the EULA agreement, you can select your current Windows XP installation to Repair Install over. Give that a try

Comment: i just tried that: the installation faild with an error message: no medium exception c0000013 parameters 7b0bf7c 7b0bf7c 7b0bf7c. what shall i do now?

Comment: How far did you get? It sounds like a hard drive issue, physically speaking. If you can, pull the hard drive out and run a CHKDSK from another computer just for S&G

Comment: I ran CHCKDSK /R and it repaired one error. after that, i tried the repair install again and ended up with exactly the same error message.

Comment: i think i found the no medium problem: a USB cardreader was plugged in.

Comment: Argh, silly things like that would do that too! Every computer that comes in here has everything stripped off the outside, then it gets plugged into our KVM so I never think of that

Comment: Windows drive letters changed from G: to C: due to the rescue install, so that most programs, including drivers, firewall and virus scanner do not work anymore [topic](http://superuser.com/questions/347134/windows-system-drive-letter-changed-after-repair-install)