# Windows system drive letter changed after repair install

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, drive-letter, repair-install

yesterday I did a repair install, because Windows froze on welcome screen after resizing its partition on a dual boot system. [corresponding question](https://superuser.com/questions/346916/Windows-xp-freezes-on-welcome-screen-after-resizing-partitions)

Everything worked fine so far, but now I am facing another challenge: The Windows drive letter changed from G: to C:, so that most programs, including drivers, firewall and virus scanner do not work anymore. I tried to reinstall the virus scanner, but the uninstaller said, that drive G: is not available.

What to do now, to get all programs running again? Is it possible, to rename C: to G: or will that mess up my system?

Answer (score 2):

Changing system drive letter is not possible via Disk Manager, but there is a workaround. Microsoft [KB Article 223188](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223188) says:

> **Warning** Do not use the procedure that is described in this article to change a drive on a computer where the drive letter has not changed. If you do so, you may not be able to start your operating system. Follow the procedure that is described in this article only to recover from a drive letter change, not to change an existing computer drive to something else. Back up your registry keys before you make this change.

There is 19 steps procedure in [that article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223188), I'd rather not copy them all here. One note, though: regedit32.exe is mentioned there, regedit32 is not available in XP. Just use regular `regedit`, right-click and chose `Permissions` as the article says.

Comment: Disk Management says: "system volume letter can not be changed"

Comment: Yeah I'm wrong. Changed my answer.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the article. Now Windows freezes in the welcome screen like before the repair install.

Comment: @tafer: I know this is late to the party, but performing a repair install should fix that.